# При GROUP BY по дате, получаю больше значений, чем без этой группировки

Tags: sql, group-by

Помогите разобраться в чем причина. Есть 2 запроса, один с группировкой по дате, второй без группировки. И в первом случае получаю общее количество (count) больше, чем во втором случае. Разница не большая, но не понятно откуда она появляется.

```
SELECT COUNT (distinct(lu.data_data1)) "КОЛИЧЕСТВО", 
(CASE 
WHEN lu.data_data2='14000000000'
THEN 'Белгородская область'
WHEN lu.data_data2='15000000000'
THEN 'Брянская область'
WHEN lu.data_data2='80000000000'
THEN 'Республика Башкортостан'
ELSE 'ДРУГИЕ РЕГИОНЫ'
END) AS "РЕГИОН",
date_trunc('day', dd.dateTime)
FROM zdrav.download_doc dd
INNER JOIN zdrav.loading_user lu ON dd.data_data1=lu.data_data1
WHERE lu.data_result='1'
AND date_trunc('day', dd.dateTime) BETWEEN '{{ ДАТА.start }}' AND '{{ ДАТА.end }}'
GROUP BY lu.data_data2, date_trunc('day', dd.dateTime)


SELECT COUNT (distinct(lu.data_data1)) "КОЛИЧЕСТВО", 
(CASE 
WHEN lu.data_data2='14000000000'
THEN 'Белгородская область'
WHEN lu.data_data2='15000000000'
THEN 'Брянская область'
WHEN lu.data_data2='80000000000'
THEN 'Республика Башкортостан'
ELSE 'ДРУГИЕ РЕГИОНЫ'
END) AS "РЕГИОН"
FROM zdrav.download_doc dd
INNER JOIN zdrav.loading_user lu ON dd.data_data1=lu.data_data1
WHERE lu.data_result='1'
AND date_trunc('day', dd.dateTime) BETWEEN '{{ ДАТА.start }}' AND '{{ ДАТА.end }}'
GROUP BY lu.data_data2
```

Comment: в прервом случае зато и строк получаете больще. Общее количество это у вас что? суммируете потом строки одинаковые в первом запросе, или что?

Answer (score 0):

Разница возникает из за того, у вас подсчет уникальных (distinct) значений. Рассмотрим простой случай. Пусть у нас есть следующие значения:

```
Group  Value
1      1
1      2
2      1
```

Если мы посчитаем количество уникальных значений Value по всей выборке, то получим значение 2 (уникальные 1 и 2). А если сделаем группировку по Group, то для первой группы будет 2 и для второй группы 1, в сумме 3.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения!
А как в таком случае быть, если необходимо подсчитать именно уникальные значения. С группировкой по дате и региону(в конкретном случае)?

Comment: @Дмитрий А как вы себе представляете результат ? Вот на том примере что я дал. В первой группе скажем 2, а во 2й ноль ? или в обоих по одному. и то и другое правдой не будет.